# SQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS returning incomplete values

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to request all the `column_name`s, `table_name`s and corresponding `data_type`s. I'm doing this using:

```
SELECT column_name, table_name, data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

However, the `data_type` occasionally returns `ARRAY`. This is technically speaking correct, as these are, for instance, `double_precision[]`.

Is it possible to return `double precision[]` instead of `ARRAY`?

Comment: There should be some other column, like `base_type`...

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto Should there? I just started with sql, but this returns a list of data I can sort of use.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-columns.html

Comment: My bad, there is a view for it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/infoschema-element-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array type can be requested by `udt_name`:

> data_type: character_data     Data type of the array elements, if it is a
>   built-in type, else USER-DEFINED (in that case, the type is identified
>   in udt_name and associated columns). [(Postgres documentation)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-element-types.html)

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f9dc79ebb10d3e8e2c380fbc0b60cc11)

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id int,
    somearrays text[],
    somearrays_i int[]
);

SELECT 
    data_type, 
    udt_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'test_table'
```

Result:

```
data_type   udt_name
integer     int4
ARRAY       _text
ARRAY       _int4
```